# cuales son lo parámetro del nodeToString

Tags: java, xml, bonita

buenos días mi pregunta esta relacionado con el nodeToString, ya que lo voy a utilizar para convertir un nodo a String pero al momento de realizar el procedimiento no me lo permite busco en la documentación de  java pero no entiendo bien los paramentos que tengo que tener al utilizar el nodeToString  realice el procedimiento con  un Node  y con un NodeList pero no me funciono, además que  cuando busco información sobre  el nodeToString encuentro es sobre toString, adjunto el código que estoy  utilizado y  el programa lo estoy haciendo en bonitasoft(7.3) con groovy

```js
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.lang.Exception;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.lang.StackTraceElement;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.AbstractSingleValueConverter;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

String ejemplo = "";
String aux = "";
boolean bandera ;


// Clean response xml document
responseDocumentBody.normalizeDocument();
// Get result node
NodeList resultList = responseDocumentBody.getElementsByTagName("*");
Element resultElement = (Element) resultList.item(0);
String weatherDataAsXML = resultElement.getTextContent();
aux  = aux +  (Element) resultList.item(0);
XStream xstream = new XStream();
String xml = xstream.toXML(aux);

// Check for empty result
if ("Data Not Found".equalsIgnoreCase(weatherDataAsXML))
 return null;

// Parse embedded XML of result
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(aux));
 try{
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|-|";
 XPath xpath=XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 Document weatherDataDocument=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);


 Node nodePrincipal=(Node)xpath.evaluate("/MortgageResults/MonthlyPrincipalAndInterest",weatherDataDocument,XPathConstants.NODE);
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|error?|";
 
 if (null == nodePrincipal)
  bandera = true;
 
  ejemplo = ejemplo +"|lo hace?|";
 if (bandera ==true)
 {
  ejemplo = ejemplo + " si hay algo ";
 }else {
  ejemplo = ejemplo +"no hay nadad";
 }
 
 NodeList childNodes = weatherNode.getChildNodes();
 
 
 
 NodeList ejemploNodo = weatherDataDocument.getDocumentElement();

 ejemplo = ejemplo +  nodeToString(ejemploNodo.getTextContent().toUpperCase());

 
}catch(Exception ex){
  StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement =ex.getStackTraceElement(0);
   int n = stackTraceElement.length;
  ejemplo = ejemplo +"---oooo---";
  for (int i = 0 ;i<n;i++ )
  {
  ejemplo = ejemplo+ " "+stackTraceElement[i].getLineNumber()+">>"+stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName();
  }
 }
return ejemplo;
```

estoy consumiendo un web service y quiere convertirlos nodos a String

```html
<MortgageResults xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<MonthlyPrincipalAndInterest>0.083785411555805267</MonthlyPrincipalAndInterest>
<MonthlyTax>0.91666666666666663</MonthlyTax>
<MonthlyInsurance>0.083333333333333329</MonthlyInsurance>
<TotalPayment>1.0837854115558052</TotalPayment>
</MortgageResults>
```

cualquier información o corrección es muy agradecida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se de donde sacaste esa función pero no parece existir en la API. Tal vez la definió otro programador, o en su defecto puedes hacer algo así:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expressionXPath).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
}
```